# Display list and details using separate controllers in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm using the following two routes in my app, but they are failing. (only one works when I switch the positions). Notice that I'm using two separate controllers. What's the correct way of specifying routes for a scenario like this?

```
Route::controller('schedulers', 'SchedulersController', [
    'getIndex' => 'schedulers.index',
    'getUpdate' => 'schedulers.edit'
]);


Route::controller('schedulers/{schedulerId}', 'ReportsController', [
    'getIndex' => 'schedulers.reports',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add route prefix

Example :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'schedulers'], function() {   

    Route::controller('/{schedulerId}', 'ReportersController', [
        'getIndex' => 'schedulers.reports',
    ]);

    Route::controller('/', 'SchedulersController', [
        'getIndex' => 'schedulers.index',
        'getUpdate' => 'schedulers.edit'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to user resource (routes.php):

```
Route::resource('schedulers', SchedulersController::class);
```

After this create SchedulersController with two methods: show, index:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SchedulersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

schedulers => SchedulersController::index

schedulers/1 => SchedulersController::show